# openorb: How to publish IP in ior

Tags: java, corba, openorb

I want to set particular ip in IOR file, I am doing it as below:

```
props.put("iiop.publishIP", "auto");
props.put("iiop.port", "60003");
props.put("iiop.hostname", "165.100.10.1");
props.put("iiop.listenAddress", "0.0.0.0");
```

When I decode the generated IOR file I am seeing the machine IP instead of configured one(165.100.10.1).I am able to see the port(60003) in decoded IOR but not the IP.

Am I missing something, can someone please help.

Comment: Solved there was typo for setting hostname instead of iiop.hostname I was using iip.hostname.

Answer (score 0):

An IOR file does not look like yours. You most probably posted a piece of Java code here.
openOrb generates an IOP file you wrote. Please post this code here.

```
props.put("iiop.publishIP", "auto");
```

might overwrite the IP you set.

Btw. you can create a corbaloc to identify your service, this could also be used inside an IOR file. E.g.,

```
corbaloc://1.2@host:port/NameService
```